# UIView's performWithoutAnimation is not working on CollectionView's reloadData

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uiviewanimation

I have a collectionView inside a TableView Cell. When I am reloading the CollectionView, I want to reload it without the animation.

Following is my code but it is not preventing the animation.

```
viewModel.reloadDataForCollectionView = { [weak self] completed in
     DispatchQueue.main.async {
         UIView.performWithoutAnimation {
             self?.wrapperView.collectionView.reloadData()
         }
     }
}
```

The WrapperView class structure is following-

```
class WrapperView: UIView {

    var collectionView: CollectionView!
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setup()
    }
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setup()
    }

    private func setup() {
        let collectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        collectionView = CollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: collectionViewFlowLayout)
        
        addSubview(collectionView)
        setupCollectionView()
    }

    private func setupCollectionView() {
        collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        //added required constraints
       
        collectionView.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: sampleCell.identifier)
    }
}
```

does any one have any idea on why it is not working. Alternatively does anyone have idea on how to stop animation for my collectionView.

Comment: A `self?.wrapperView.collectionView.layoutIfNeeded()` right after the `reloadData` might work. Also try keeping a reference to the old contentOffset (before the reload) and set it after the reload with `.setContentOffset(oldContentOffset, animated: false)`.

Comment: Tried your suggestion but didn't work either. By the way, the data is laid out properly, I just want stop the flicker, so I need the animation to be disabled.

Comment: Might be worth trying either `collectionView.reloadSections([0])` or `collectionView.reloadItems(at: collectionView.indexPathsForVisibleItems)`. If that doesn't work, see if you can put together a [mre] so we can test your code.

Comment: The code is highly convoluted. So, can't share the entire code. The thing, upon data load, I am reloading the collection view, so that point, I don't have access to index path or section number. I need to call the reload method. Besides for testing purpose, I tried reloadSections() and same result.